# I can't get the li's to be in my gray nav bar?

Tags: html, html-lists, nav

I have two links that I want to be on the right side of the navbar. I am not sure what I am missing here but if anyone can take a look at this I would greatly appreciate it. Here is my rep.it https://gregs-list.leezamartinez.repl.co/

I have tried to put them in a span and move the span to the top of the page but it just doesn't seem to work. I apologize if this is a stupid question I cannot seem to figure it out.

I want the Post and Account links to be in the right side of the navbar
https://gregs-list.leezamartinez.repl.co/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is due to the fact that your **h1** has a **100% width**, the best approach here is to make the nav tag **display:flex**, **justify-content:space-between** and **align-items:center** to center everything vertically.

**Example**

```css
html {
 padding: 10px;
 padding-right: 10px;
 padding-left: 10px;
}

a {
 text-decoration: none;
 display: inline;
}

a::hover {
  text-decoration-line: underline;
}
body {
 box-sizing: border-box;
 font-family: 'Nunito', sans-serif;
}

main {
  padding: 5%;
  margin: auto;
  padding-top:86px;
}

nav {
  position: fixed;
  margin: -18px;
  background-color: whitesmoke;
  width: 100%;
  height: 65px;
  text-align: left;
  display:flex;
  justify-content:space-between;
  align-items:center;
  z-index:9;
}

li {
  float: right;
  color: purple;
  list-style: none;
  font-size: 20px;
  padding: 8px;
  margin-right: 8px;
}

ul {
  display: inline;
  padding: 5px;
}

span {
  color:rgb(184, 179, 179);
  text-decoration-style: none;
}

p {
  color: blue;
  font-weight: bold;
}

placeholder {
  font-famiy: 'Nunito', sans-serif;
  color:lightgrey;
}

#mag {
  height: 31px;
  width: 29.5px;
  display: -webkit-inline-box;
  position: absolute;
  border: 1px solid #DDDDDD;
  border-radius: 3px;
}

h1 {
  font-famiy: 'Nunito', sans-serif;
  font-size: 25px;
  font-weight: 700;
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 5px;
}

input {
  height: 33px;
  font-color: whitesmoke;
  font-size: 20px;
  width: 400px;
  padding: 5px;
  border: 2px solid whitesmoke; 
}

label {
  font-weight: bold;
}

#button1 {
  width: 102px;
  height: 40px;
  padding: 12px 28px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  float: left;
  border: 1px solid rgb(228, 228, 228);
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 14px;
  background-color: ghostwhite;
 
}

#button2 {
  width: 155px;
  height: 40px;
  padding: 12px 28px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  float: left;
  border: 1px solid rgb(228, 228, 228);
  background-color: ghostwhite;
  font-size: 14px;
}

#button3 {
  width: 100px;
  height: 40px;
  padding: 12px 28px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 14px;
  background-color: ghostwhite;
  border: 1px solid rgb(228, 228, 228);
}

.container {
  position: absolute;
  padding-top: 10px;
}

form {
  padding: 20px;
  padding-right: 55px;
  padding-left: 0;
}
```

```html
<nav>
 <h1>Greg's List</h1>
  <ul>
      <li> <a href="#">Account</a></li>
      <li> <a href="#">Post</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
<main>
 <div class="box">
  <label>Search jobs</label>
 </div> 
  <form action="#">
     <input id='search' type="search" name="search" placeholder="Search software jobs" /> <a href='#'> <img id='mag' src="https://tf-assets-prod.s3.amazonaws.com/tf-curric/WEB-DEV-001/2.4.6_challenge_design_to_code/magnifying-glass.png" alt="magnifying glass" /></a>
    </form>

     <button type="button" id="button1"> prev</button>
      <button a href="#" type="button"id="button2">1 to 100 of 179</button>
      <button type="button"id="button3"> next > </button>
      <div class="container">
        <p><span>June 22</span><a href="#"> Technical Project Manager <span> Midtwon East</span></a></p>
        <p><span>June 21</span><a href="#"> Frontend Developer <span> SoHo</span></a></p>
        <p><span>June 20</span><a href="#"> Senior Python Developer / Cofounder<span> Flatiron</span></a></p>
      </div>
      </main>
```

Also, bear in mind that you had a lot of markup errors in your HTML, I've corrected them in the snippet above. Plus you needed some padding for your main tag due to the fixed navigation bar (that also needed a **z-index:9** in order to keep other things from showing above it).

Comment: @leemartinez You're welcome! Please accept the answer if it helped you, so other can benefit from it too. Thanks!